# How to decrease space between bars in barchart using JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart and trying to move the bars little closer to other bars in BarChart.

I have gone through other question and answers in Stack Overflow and it is a duplicate question, but it's not successful here.

```
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Fund Transfer", "Transaction Results", "Summary Of Transaction", bardataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    if(chart != null)
    {
        int width = 760;
        int height = 470;
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
        renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.03);
        final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, width, height, info);
    }
```

Currently I getting BarChart output as below.
[image]

So as per my above code what change I need to do for decreasing space b/w bars?? AnyOne suggest me.

Comment: `StackedBarRenderer` gives you some flexibility to play around with the bar spacing and margin spacing. Did you try that one?

Comment: Tried but still same

Comment: You have to play around with methods like `setLowerMargin()`, `setCategoryMargin()` and `setUpperMargin()` within `CategoryAxis` to gain control of the spacing. It is possible.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.